# Custom select with javascript and with parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want create a custom select with javascript and css...I found this library that is very useful: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

I tried to implement on my website (you can see here: http://warm-bastion-7866.herokuapp.com/ )

The problem is that when i click on the select, it not open the menu...i found that the "real problem" is that it not add the class "open" on the parent div(div with class="btn-group bootstrap-select bla bli").

The same problem i have with the lib of Flat UI: http :// designmodo.com/demo/flat-ui/

Also Flat UI use a lib called (bootstrap-select, like the script linked previously), i have the same problem that not add the class "open" to the parent div.

I tried also to load only few js and css lib, but nothing changes.

I think that the problem is with something that goes in conflict...firebug no give me error :(

Any Help ?

Thanks.

EDIT: http ://jsfiddle.net/n5NEU/7/ (I must add the whitespace, because i can't insert more of two links).

Comment: post a fiddle it will be easy to edit.

Comment: Ok, http://jsfiddle.net/n5NEU/7/

Comment: i have posted an answer. accept it if it works for you. all i did is removed dropdown reference from your fiddle.

Comment: I know that this is not the issue here but maybe you could try JQuery UI it is very easy to use.

Comment: The problem is with bootstrap-dropdown...now i must know if goes in conflict or no...bootstrap-dropdown is already in bootstrap.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me that you're using [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).
You can download their scripts [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and reference the css and js in your project.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/WWtew/).

**HTML**

```
<select id="id_select" class="selectpicker bla bla bli">
        <option>cow</option>
        <option>aaa</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

**NOTE:**

You do not need to include [bootstrap-dropdown.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js), especially cause you're referencing the 2.3.2 but you seem to be using bootstrap ver 3.

Comment: Umh, i'm using it: http://jsfiddle.net/n5NEU/7/ where is the difference ?

Comment: You're including bootstrap-dropdown.js which you is already included in bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: Sorry i use 2.3.2, only that i linked for jsfiddle the lastest bootstrap version(3) from cdn...anyway bootstrap-dropdown is included in bootstrap.js already ?

Comment: Yes. You can see what's included in the [customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html).

Comment: Richard, if you think my solution helped you could accept the answer. Cheers.

Comment: I have done correctly ? sorry but I'm new :) anyway i choice you over the other answers, because is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed bootstrap-dropdown.js reference from your fiddle and it is working like a charm now. may be that dropdown file is conflicting.